# How to set up HTTPS on Amazon EC2 with Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I have requested a certificate in Amazon Certificate Manager. Now it has status 'issued'. 
In EC2 console I have created Load Balancer. There are 2 listeners: HTTP and HTTPS. I tried Application Load Balancer and Classic Load Balancer, but I can't connect to my site via HTTPS.

My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #listen 443 ssl;

    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent; 

    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    root /home/ubuntu/www/site.com/wordpress;
    index index.php;

    client_max_body_size 20m;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;


    location ~* ^/(\.htaccess|xmlrpc\.php)$ {
        return 404;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
            expires max;
    }

    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        set $is_https 'off';
            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto ~ 'https') {
                set $is_https 'on';
            }
        proxy_set_header HTTPS $is_https;

        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
            break;
     }
            #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # permalinks
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

How can I import the certificate manually? Or there is a way to set up HTTPS connection with the Amazon certificate?

[image: Godaddy domain DNS settings]

Comment: Did you set the certificate to ELB? Doc is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-add-or-delete-listeners.html

Comment: @minamijoyo yes, I did. Do I need to Configure Back-end Instance Authentication (Optional)?

Comment: No, you don't need back-end authentication. Is there any output in nginx access or error log?

Comment: Are you hitting the load balancer or are you still hitting the server directly?

Comment: @MarkB what do you mean?

Comment: You have to start using the address of the load balancer instead of the EC2 server. You have to send traffic through the load balancer. If you are still hitting the EC2 server directly then the load balancer isn't being used.

Comment: @MarkB where I have to configure it?

Comment: In your DNS settings

Comment: I have updated my post. Please see my DNS config. It still doesn't work. What should I use in 'A record'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135497/discussion-between-alex-pavlov-and-mark-b).

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ACM cert, you can just select that certificate from the ELB Listener for HTTPS/443 and you don't need to bother setting up the SSL config in your nginx instance. Just have it respond on port 80.

You just need both HTTP/80 and HTTPS/443 in the ELB to HTTP port 80 on the instance (This sample is using the Classic ELB)

[image]

If the Cert is in ACM you should see it in the dropdown once when you select "Change" under SSL Certificate.

Now you just need to make sure your ELB security group is set up to allow Ingress from 80/443 and Egress from 80. And you need to make sure your instance allows Ingress from the ELB Security Group.

Comment: Yes, I did this. But  as @MarkB said I should configure my dns settings to use ELB. How can I do this without using Route53? In my Godaddy account I have an A record with name: '@' and value 'EC2 ip'.

Comment: In the ELB description you will see a DNS record. Try hitting that directly and it should work. Then just use/create a CNAME record in GoDaddy pointing to that ELB DNS.

Comment: I have updated my post. Please see my domain config. HTTPS still doesn't work. When I try to open url directly by ELB DNS name, it redirects me to https://ELB_DNS and show an error 'Your connection is not private' because  its security certificate is from *.mydomain.com

Comment: @Alex Pavlov - You should first confirm that the ELB is working correctly. Don't worry about the DNS config until then. In the ELB Instance tab, confirm that your instances are "InService". if they are not, the ELB wont allow any traffic through. Once you have that working then hit the ELB DNS directly (found in the Description Tab). If that works, then you can start configuring the external DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your ELB setup and port mapping, the `$https` variable won't always work when your instance is behind an AWS ELB (h/t @Michael - sqlbot). You should use `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` header instead and move your rewrite rule inside the **IF** statement that checks for the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` header:

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;

  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$1 permanent;
  }

  .
  .
  .
}
```

**Note on Security Groups**

Also, you need to ensure that your load balancer can communicate with registered targets on both the listener port and the health check port. For more info:

[Security Groups for Your Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-update-security-groups.html)

[Security Groups for Your Classic Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-groups.html)

Comment: It reirects me to https, but doesn't work. There are not errors in nginx log.  In load balancer I have the listeners: 1) HTTP 80 --> HTTP 80, 2) HTTPS 443 --> HTTP 80. In load balancer on tab Instances it has status 'OutOfService'.

Comment: Why are you setting the listening port to 80 for the HTTPS protocol? The HTTPS listener should listening on port 443.

Comment: @KhalidT.  *"HTTPS won't work behind AWS ELB"* is appropriate advice in this case, but for reference, [it is not always true](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: You're absolutely right :) I have updated my answer. Thanks.